# How to update HighChart series inside setInterval method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph, highcharts

I have a spline graph which compare page views count of  today and last 7 days of one host. Once graph is loaded in browser, a new point added periodically using load method given below. Things are working fine here.

There is option to add or remove new host using check box.

**My problem:**
When user select new host, graph is populated successfully with older host.
But graph is not getting updated for new host periodically.
As per code below HighChart series is passed in setInterval method which is not getting updated for new host.

My Question:
How to update series, so I can add point for newly added host periodically.

Please guide me...
Thanks in advance.

```
 events : {
                    load : function() {
                        var thisseries = this.series;
                        setInterval(function() {
                        var data = getMegaGraphPointsForFiveMin();
                        var index = 0;
                        for(var i = 0 ; i< data.length; i++){
                            var series =  thisseries[index];
                            var innerData = data[i];
                            var dataArray = innerData.dataArrayP;
                            var xval = dataArray[0].x;
                            var yval = dataArray[0].y;
                            series.addPoint([xval, yval], true, false);
                            index = index + 2;
                        }
                        },  60*1000);// add new page view count in every  min dynamically.
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Have you tried adding in a [redraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.redraw) in your load function?

Comment: It is hard to image how all of this work without any example. Could you try to provide us with such? What getMegaGraphPointsForFiveMin() function does?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to my question above.

**Problem :** Load method is called every time when user select check box of any host.
And in Load method we are using setInterval() method and it run after given interval  continuously in background.

**Solution :** So on every load method call i clear the older setInterval as given below.
It may help to some beginners like me

Find the code below

//Global variable

var myTimervar;

```
events : {
                load : function() {
                    var thisseries = this.series;
                    if(myTimervar){
                        window.clearInterval(myTimervar);
                    }
                    myTimervar = setInterval(function() {
                        var data = getMegaGraphPointsForFiveMin();
                        var index = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var series = thisseries[index];
                            var innerData = data[i];
                            var dataArray = innerData.dataArrayP;
                            var xval = dataArray[0].x;
                            var yval = dataArray[0].y;
                            series.addPoint([ xval, yval ], true, false);
                            index = index + 2;
                        }
                    }, 300 * 1000);// add new page view count in every 5 min
                                    // dynamically.
                }
            }
```